# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'

Tags: python, windows, import, spyder

I am using Spyder in Windows machine  to execute below Python program.  But the program fails with error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'"

I installed paramiko by going to command line . So I know paramiko is installed.
But it is showing error from Spyder. Can you please help me to fix this issue ?

```
import os
import paramiko

server="xxx"
username="xxx"
password="xxx"
localpath="C:\Temp\MyLog.txt"
remotepath="C:\Temp"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Well it depends how you installed the library. If you're using Anaconda (presumably) then you should use `conda install`. It's possible that you installed it into a different version of Python on your system than the one that Spyder uses.

Comment: @ roganjosh, can you please explain more "should use conda install" ? What does it mean ? Do I need  reinstall Ananconda ? Or do some setup change ? Please explain

Comment: Start menu --> "Anaconda3" --> "Anaconda Prompt". In there type `conda install paramiko`. If you just use `pip` or `pip3` and Anaconda isn't the main python used by the system, it won't be installed in the Anaconda library.

Comment: @ roganjosh, thanks a lot . It worked

Comment: @roganjosh Got the same error. I use pip but cannot import this module. Weird thing is I can import `paramiko` module in python console. It only happens when I running the python script that contains `import paramiko`